# how to know if one of my childs get some mouse events?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

If I m a custom `Tcontrol` and I want to know if one of my **childs** (or childs of my childs, etc..) get some **mouse events** (like `mouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseMove`, etc..) How I can do under Firemonkey? I think it's impossible (except playing with `CMGesture` but this is different "flow" than the one used by mouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, etc)

In a nutshell is there any mechanism to propagate mouse events in firemonkey ?

Comment: Why not simply assign `OnMouse(Down|Up)` event handlers to your child controls?

Comment: I think ptInRect() will be very useful with a loop when the parent receives mouse move event

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout OP doesn't looking just for `OnMouseMove` event handler.

Comment: @Sami once you get `OnMouseMove` you can get `OnEnter, OnLeave, OnMouseDown  OnMouseUp, OnClick, OnDbleClick`. `OnMouseMove` is vital when you try todo every thing on your own (I have done this before)

Comment: @loki from a vcl stand point (I do not use fire monkey) not all controls will propagate mouse events to their parents

Comment: @Nasreddine Isn't this a Firemonkey question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Since Fire monkey and Vcl are developed by the same company (emba says that the same knowledge for vcl can be used to develop in Firemonkey with few differences), I thought sharing some of the problems I had to face would be a good Idea.

Comment: @Nasreddine The frameworks are very different. This question requires specific knowledge of Firemonkey.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i can't because I want to do a custom Tscrollbox control and assign OnMousexxx to all childreen is not viable option, especially that i also need to catch even in child of child of child ... of child control

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout unfortuntly ptInRect is not a viable option their is no correct way to use it in a loop

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it's very specific to firemonkey, i m surprise that in firemonkey their is no mecanism to propagate event to their parents

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24397 :)